# Why is my div being pushed down?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the `white` box, `topBoxFlag` up to the top of its parent `topBox`. However, due to the relative layout it's being pushed down below the red box. How would I push it upwards? I tried an absolute layout, but decided this wouldn't work as it'd occur for all of my other boxes and I feel it'd be extremely inefficient. Is there something like `float` that can push it right to the top of its parent?

```css
    body
    {
     background-color: #C6E0F5;
    }
    
    #wrapper
    {
     position: relative;
     margin: auto;
     width: 1000px;
     height: 2900px;
     max-width: 1000px;
     background-color: #C6E0F5;
    }
    
    #header
    {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 170px;
     background-color: #00247D;
    }
    
    #navbar 
    {
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      bottom: 20px;
      height: 35px;
      text-align: center; 
      background-color: #CF142B;
    }
      #navbar ul li 
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        font-size: 25px;
        display: inline; 
    }
      #navbar ul li a 
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff; 
    }
    
    .topbox
    {
     height: 400px;
     width: 800;
     margin: auto;
     background-color: #00247D;
    }
    
    .topbox h1
    {
     font-size: 35px;
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #CF142B;
    }
    
    .topbox #topboxFlag
    {
     float: right;
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
     background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .partybox
    {
     height: 400px;
     width: 800;
     margin: auto;
     background-color: #00247D;
     margin-top: 15px;
    }
    
    .partybox h1
    {
     font-size: 35px;
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #CF142B;
    }
```

```html
         <html>
        
        <head>
         <title>Learn which parties are doing what</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
         <div id = "wrapper">
        
          <div id = "header">
           
           <div id = "logo"></div>
        
          </div>
        
          <div id = "navbar">
            <ul>
             <li><a href="index.html">Major Parties</a></li>
             <li><a href="minor.html">Minor Parties</a></li>
             <li><a href="whyvote.html">Why Vote</a></li>
             <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        
          <div class = "topbox">
        
           <h1>The Conservative Party</h1>
        
           <div id = "topboxFlag"></div>
        
          </div>
        
          <div class = "partybox">
        
           <h1>The Labour Party</h1>
        
           <div id = "partyboxFlag"></div>
        
          </div>
        
          <div class = "partybox">
        
           <h1>The Liberal Democrats</h1>
        
          </div>
        
          <div class = "partybox">
        
           <h1>The UK Independence Party</h1>
        
          </div>
        
          <div class = "partybox">
        
           <h1>The Green Party</h1>
        
          </div>
        
          <div class = "partybox">
           <h1>The Scottish National Party</h1>
          </div>
        
         </div>
        
        
        
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you put this into a JSfiddle?

Comment: @BigRabbit better  yet, a stack snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more css to you stylesheet and you are good to go.

```
.topbox h1{
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
```

Since you `topboxFlag` class has a float, you should also add float to your heading.

```css
body {
  background-color: #C6E0F5;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 2900px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #C6E0F5;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #00247D;
}
#navbar {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  bottom: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #CF142B;
}
#navbar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
.topbox {
  height: 400px;
  width: 800;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #00247D;
}
.topbox h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #CF142B;
}
.topbox #topboxFlag {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.partybox {
  height: 400px;
  width: 800;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #00247D;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.partybox h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #CF142B;
}
.topbox h1 {
  margin: 0;

  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learn which parties are doing what</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">

      <div id="logo"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Major Parties</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="minor.html">Minor Parties</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="whyvote.html">Why Vote</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="topbox">

      <h1>The Conservative Party</h1>

      <div id="topboxFlag"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="partybox">

      <h1>The Labour Party</h1>

      <div id="partyboxFlag"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="partybox">

      <h1>The Liberal Democrats</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="partybox">

      <h1>The UK Independence Party</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="partybox">

      <h1>The Green Party</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="partybox">
      <h1>The Scottish National Party</h1>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the flag div first?

```
<div class="topbox">
    <div id="topboxFlag></div>
    <h1>The Conservative Party</h1>
</div>
```